# Create automapper configuration using expression tree

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I'm going through a little problem, i'm using automapper and creating maps from a Expression Tree or Reflection but i'm not obtain success, i will explain the problem.

Basically in this code i'm trying pass a expression tree independent to type of property, but this exception occours in 'MapFrom':

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Only member accesses are allowed.
>   dest => Convert(dest.Shipping.Method, Object) '

Exists a workarround for this ?

```
 var peDestination = Expression.Parameter(destination.GetType(), "dest");
   var peSource = Expression.Parameter(source.GetType(), "src");

    if (propertyMap.Destination.IndexOf('.') >= 0)
    {
         Expression destinationExpression = peDestination;
         foreach (var navigatinoPropertieDestination in propertyMap.Destination.Split('.'))
               destinationExpression = Expression.Property(destinationExpression,navigatinoPropertieDestination);

          var sourceExpression = Expression.Property(peSource, propertyMap.Source);

var sourceMapFromExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(                                
  Expression.Convert(sourceExpression, typeof(object)), new ParameterExpression[] { peSource });

     //// dest => dest.Property
    var destinationMapFromExpression =
                            Expression.Lambda<Func<TDestination, object>>
                                (Expression.Convert(destinationExpression, typeof(object)), new ParameterExpression[] { peDestination });

map.ForPath(destinationMapFromExpression, a => a.MapFrom(sourceMapFromExpression));
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to create a mapping configuration dynamically according to what the user predefines via UI, for example ObjectA.PropertyA and map to ObjectB.InnerObject.Field.  I have a example on my github.

Comment: We have a string based `ForMember`, not a string based `ForPath`. I don't think that makes much sense. You can always have another map and then you don't need the extra indirection.

Comment: I didn't understand what about 'extra indirection', I already passed the string "Shipping.Method" and it just breaks, the workaround I did was to invoke via Expression since it is from one property to another inside the object.

Comment: That dot is the indirection :) You're not using it as designed, that's why. I think you should implement your own thing.

Comment: Ok @LucianBargaoanu thanks for your help. I saw that you went through something similar in IncludeMembers, basically that would be the solution you had proposed, thanks anyway.

Comment: That's different, because the boxing there was imposed by the AM API. But we'll take a PR for a reasonable use case.

Comment: Ok, thanks Lucian. I open PR

Comment: Can you see another way to write an expression without using 'Convert.Expression' to bind with AM? Unfortunately I can't think of another way to do this using AM, if I don't have it I think I will have to implement something separately.

Comment: I don't see it. That `Convert` is there because you put it there. But do you see how you can avoid `ForPath` by having a map for the first property in the `ForPath` expression? Because that would allow you to use the string based `ForMember`.

Comment: the 'ForMember' based on string also gives an error when navigating between objects since it is made to access a direct property and not an 'InnerDestination', Convert is necessary because I only know the type of the property in Runtime and when I put it an expression where the property is an integer and the return is Func <TSource, object> () it overflows a cast exception.

Comment: basically the navigation is Source.Property -> Destination.InnerDestination.Property so the string-based ForMember doesn't work and I need to create an expression dynamically. ForMember only works for Source.Property -> Destination.Property.

Comment: for direct properties I managed to do it and everything worked out the only problem is when it is a navigation property

Comment: You just need another map, from Source to InnerDestination and ForMember InnerDestination, MapFrom Source.

Comment: I had tried it this way too, it didn't work. I will do my own implementation. Thank you very much for your time Lucian.